# Converting a C-ctyle string encoded as a character array to a Java String

Tags: java, c, string, terminator

I have a C-style string encoded as an array of characters in Java, but I would like to convert this array to a Java String. I tried using the matching constructor call,

```
String toRet = new String(new char[]{'B','A','D','\0', 'G', 'A', 'R', 'B', 'A', 'G', 'E'});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toRet.toCharArray()));
```

But the result is incorrect, and in fact oddly buggy. Here's what the above code outputs:

```
[B, A, D,
```

And here's what I want

```
[B, A, D]
```

I'm running on openJdk6 on Ubuntu. I haven't tested the above code on other VM's.

Comment: You perhaps can have a look to [this:][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487023/how-should-i-terminate-a-char-array-before-converting-into-a-string-in-java

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a String to get involved here. Just copy into a new array that is one char shorter than your input array. The method to use for this task is `Arrays.copyOf`.

The reason your output is buggy is because strings in Java have nothing to do with null-terminators. Your first line of code creates a string whose last character is the null-character.

### Response to your updated question

If you have garbage following the null-char, you can use `new String(inputArray)`, then find the null-char with `String.indexOf('\0')` and use that in a `String.substring` operation to cut out the unneeded part. However, it would be still simpler (from the time/space complexity perspective) to just iterate over the array to locate the null-char and then use `Arrays.copyOf` with that index as cutoff point.

Comment: Modified question to clarify.

Comment: O.K. It, so it takes a few steps, but that's fine. I'll mark this as an accepted answer whenever the system lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim()` to remove space chars:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toRet.trim().toCharArray()));
```

Comment: This works when the null terminator character ends the string, but not when there are garbage characters after the null terminator I want to ignore.

Cool trick though, I didn't know trim() also removes \0's at the end.

Comment: `trim()` defines whitespace as `\u0000` to `\u0020` inclusive - it does _not_ use the Unicode definition of whitespace, nor `Character.isWhitespace`.

Answer (score 0):

To confuse people that have to maintain your code, you could write:

```
char[] dta = new char[]{'B','A','D','\0', 'G', 'A', 'R', 'B', 'A', 'G', 'E'};

String string = (dta[0] == '\0') ? "" : (new String(dta)).split("\0")[0];
System.out.println(string.toCharArray());
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

    "\0".split("\0")[0]

throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Indeed, so what should the resulting String contain in that case? To avoid another line of code: String string = dta[0] == '\0' ? "" : (new String(dta)).split("\0")[0];