# Is it correct/efficient to call trim() after a byte[] to String conversion?

Tags: java

Suppose a byte array ending by a lot of zeros.
The call

```
new String(barray,"UTF-8")
```

will give me a string with wrong length as 0 bytes will be translate to \0 (this cuz java doesn't consider strings like char sequences termined by a \0).
Is it correct this function:

```
public String convertFromByteArray(byte[] a){
    String s = new String(a,"UTF-8");
    return s.trim();
```

Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a C-ctyle string encoded as a character array to a Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027588/converting-a-c-ctyle-string-encoded-as-a-character-array-to-a-java-string)

Comment: @BheshGurung Phate is asking about efficiency, in the question you've referenced there's nothing about that

Comment: Very good thanks! Anyway I will go with the 6x speed version as I am 100% sure my byte string will not have null bytes in between :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] barray= new byte[99999999];
        barray[0]=72;
        barray[1]=101;
        barray[2]=108;
        barray[3]=108;
        barray[4]=111;
        barray[5]=33;
        for (int k = 6; k < barray.length; k++) {
            barray[k]=0;
        }
        try {
            long a=System.nanoTime();
            convertFromByteArray(barray);
            long b=System.nanoTime();
            long tot_1=b-a;
            long c=System.nanoTime();
            convertFromByteArray2(barray);
            long d=System.nanoTime();
            long tot_2=d-c;
            System.out.println(tot_1 +" - "+tot_2+" "+(tot_1*1.0/tot_2));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static String convertFromByteArray(byte[] a) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        String s = new String(a,"UTF-8");
        return s.trim();
    }
    public static String convertFromByteArray2(byte[] barray) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        int i=0;
        while(barray[i++]!=0);

        return new String(barray,0,i-1,"UTF-8");
    }
```

Output:

```
426205180 - 69702 6114.676479871453
```

6k x faster

**EDIT:**

As [@SotiriosDelimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) and [@BheshGurung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/738746/bhesh-gurung) noticed, if there's a byte 0 followed by a valid char, the solution is incorrect.

For covering all cases,

```
public static String convertFromByteArray2(byte[] barray) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int i=barray.length-1;
    while(barray[i--]==0 && i>=0);
    return new String(barray,0,i+2,"UTF-8");
}
```

Tested with http://ideone.com/mg2U23

3x faster.

Comment: very nice! I would use a charset item at place of UTF-8 but I think this is the best too

Comment: So what about read two bytes at once for a character, and return when there is two consecutive `\0`? so the problme about 0 in the middle may get resolved.